# Adding common functionality to Buttons without using classes

Tags: javascript, jsp

I've been trying to build a forum page from scratch for my internship (I know I can get software for that online but I'm doing this mostly for the learning opportunity).

Upon opening the page you can see all the different topics and when you click on the topic I want to fetch the relevant replies from the back-end and dynamically create the forum page.

Since the process for all is essentially the same (with only the fetched data being different) I was wondering if there was a way to provide all the buttons on the page the same functionality WITHOUT USING CLASSES as I'm primarily using them for providing CSS.

Comment: are you talking about look and feel of the buttons? same functionality for all teh buttons doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Using classes to add listeners to elements doesn't interfere with those elements' styling.

Comment: @Titus Thanks man that makes sense. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attributes to bind an event handler to elements and identify which exact element was clicked from the event object.

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="clickHandler(event)">Click me</div>
<button onclick="clickHandler(event)">Click me too</button><br>
<button onclick="clickHandler(event)">Click me three</button>
```

That being said, the above practice is out dated. You can read about other ways to bind events in [MDN Introduction to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Also, **Classes are not just for CSS**. They are used to select elements and it's a common practice to add classes to elements in order to identify them in the DOM using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Comment: I think the jQuery function $(".p").click(function() will serve my requirements. Thanks!

Comment: `$(".p")` is a selector that selects elements with a class `p`. If you want to find the `p` tags you need to remove the dot `.`.

Comment: Shouldn't have used p there.  Just meant something like $(".xyz")

Comment: Well, now it's clearer. What confused me is that it doesn't fit your requirement - *WITHOUT USING CLASSES*. It's better this way.